# Why prolog does not recognise arguments in a query?

Tags: prolog

I have this portion of code as base case in a recursive predicate.

```
riduci_lista_valori([[V, N]],m_var,Lr):-
   member(V, m_var),
   Lr =[N].
```

The problem is that when I perform my query it does not unify correctly the arguments of the predicate with its parameters.

Given the code, my query is: `riduci_lista_valori([[a, 5]], [c,e], F).`
And I expect Prolog to return `F = [5]`.
Debugging the code seems it doesn't recognize properly the arguments because it does not unify like: `V = a`, `N = 5` `m_var = [c,e]` but it gives:
`1 = [[a, 5]]` and `2 = [c, e]`.

Whereas if I prompt : `[[V, N]] = [[a,5]].` it makes the correct unification:
`V = a` , `N = 5`.

What am I doing wrong? thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To detect causes of failure in Prolog, use **declarative debugging**:

Add the following definitions to your program:

```
:- op(950,fy, *).
*_.
```

Now, you can use `(*)/1` to *generalize away* specific goals.

For example:

```
riduci_lista_valori([[V, N]], m_var, Lr) :-
        * member(V, m_var),
        * Lr =[N].
```

*Even with this much more general version*, we get:

```
?- riduci_lista_valori([[a, 5]], [c,e], F).
false.
```

This means that if you expect the query to *succeed at all*, you need to **further generalize** your program. See what actually remains of the program:

```
riduci_lista_valori([[V, N]], m_var, Lr) :- true.
```

This snippet is already **too specific**. Let us generalize it like this:

```
riduci_lista_valori([[V, N]], Var, Lr) :- true.
```

Now the query *succeeds*:

```
?- riduci_lista_valori([[a, 5]], [c,e], F).
true.
```

Thus, this second argument of your clause head is a good candidate for thorough inspection!

Maybe you meant to use a **variable** instead of the **atom** `m_var`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've learnt something new about declarative debbugging. But your last line saved my night :)

Comment: s(X), what an awesome idea!

Comment: Could you include a reference that explains\expands `declarative debugging` with regards to Prolog; especially the use of `op(920,fy, *).` This is a nice technique I would like to incorporate into my Prolog tool box. If you would like this as a separate question just ask. Maybe it should be a tag with references like [tag:failure-slice]

Comment: Yes, please file a separate question for this interesting topic, so that we can collect the references there!